# How to remove element before and after the index in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, draggable, vuedraggable

I've got an array with arrays:

```
[[], [0], []. [3], [], [6], []]
```

Those elements are in a vue component using draggable JS. Draggable has 2 properties @start and @end. The will trigger whenever I drag or drop an element in the array.  Whenever I drag one of those elements, I want to remove the empty array before and after the current element. So when I drag [6], the array should look like:

```
[[], [0], []. [3], [6]]
```

isVisible is triggered at @start so whenever I select an element. How can I remove the element before and after the index in an array? I thought using slice?

```
isVisible (val, index) {
   if (val[0] === 6) {
   this.array.splice(this.array[index - 1], 1)
   this.array.splice(this.array[index + 1], 1)
}
```

Comment: When modifying an iterable, while keeping some state about an index, care needs to be taken. When you do `this.array.splice(this.array[index - 1], 1)`, indices of later elements shift one up, so your index isn't valid anymore. A potential solution may be changing the order of the calls, delete the one behind first, then the one before. Also, i think you misunderstood the signature of `Array.prototype.splice`. The first parameter is an index, not an element.

Comment: `splice`-remove preferable has to be processed from an array's right to its left side in order to not run out of sync with the indices one wants to `splice`-remove from.

Answer (score 2):

After you remove the element before, the indexes of all the remaining elements shift down, so the element after is now at `index`, not `index + 1`.

To avoid this problem, the simplest way is to remove the element after first.

```
isVisible (val, index) {
    if (val[0] === 6) {
        this.array.splice(this.array[index + 1], 1)
        this.array.splice(this.array[index - 1], 1)
    }
}
```

Note that if this is part of a loop, the loop index will need to be adjusted down to reflect that the element before the current index has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach would be filtering the original array and return a new one with data you want:

```js
let arr = [ [], [0], [], [3], [], [6], [] ];
console.log('Source:'+arr);

function filterDragged(dragged, arr) {
  return arr.filter((e,i,a)=>{
    if ((a[i] && a[i].length==0) &&
        (a[i+1] && a[i+1].length!=0 && a[i+1][0]===dragged))
      return false;

    if ((a[i] && a[i].length==0) &&
        (a[i-1] && a[i-1].length!=0 && a[i-1][0]===dragged))
      return false;

    return true;
  });
}

console.log('Result:'+filterDragged(6, arr));
console.log('Result:'+filterDragged(3, arr));
```